# How to print missing values of an array on a given input range in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

In this JavaScript code, I want to print the missing values after giving input in an input range. But the problem is it is printing all the values on that input range. What can be the possible changes in the `alreadyHave()` function?

```js
 console.log("Enter the lower limit: ");
    let lower_limit= parseInt(window.prompt(""));
    console.log(lower_limit);
    
    console.log("Enter the upper limit: ");
    let upper_limit= parseInt(window.prompt(""));
    console.log(upper_limit);
    
    console.log(`input any number between ${lower_limit} and ${upper_limit}: `);
    let arr=[], temp=[];
    
    for(let i=lower_limit; i<=upper_limit; i++){
        arr=parseInt(window.prompt(""));
        if(arr>=lower_limit && arr<=upper_limit){
            temp.push(arr);
        }
        else{
            break;
        }
    }
    console.log(temp);
    
    for(let i=lower_limit; i<=upper_limit; i++){
        if(alreadyHave(i)){
            console.log(i);
        };
    }
     function alreadyHave(value){
        for(let i=0; i<=temp.length; i++){
            if(value !== parseInt(temp[i])){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
console.log("Enter the lower limit: ");
let lower_limit= parseInt(window.prompt(""));
console.log(lower_limit);

console.log("Enter the upper limit: ");
let upper_limit= parseInt(window.prompt(""));
console.log(upper_limit);

console.log(`input any number between ${lower_limit} and ${upper_limit}: `);
let arr=[], temp=[];

for(let i=lower_limit; i<=upper_limit; i++){
    arr=parseInt(window.prompt(""));
    if(arr>=lower_limit && arr<=upper_limit){
        temp.push(arr);
    }
    else{
        break;
    }
}
console.log(temp);

for(let i=lower_limit; i<=upper_limit; i++){
    if(!temp.includes(i)){
    console.log(i);
    }
}
```

This will give you what you want